# Finding count of matched items for every permutation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a result set that counts the number of employees that match a set of all permutations for several categories. This is only an example, as the real details cannot be shared and is more complex.

I have two categories: Gender and Class. Gender has the options of Male/Female. Class has the options of 1/2/3. I've used a cross join as below to find all six permutations of those two categories (M/1, M/2, M/3, F/1, F/2, F/3)

```
    WITH 
      cteGender AS (SELECT Gender FROM Genders),
      cteClass AS (SELECT Class FROM Classes)

    SELECT * FROM cteGender CROSS JOIN cteClass
```

Next, I have a list of employees that has columns: Name, Gender, Class. My goal is to create a result set that displays the count of each employee whose gender and class matches the permutation set, including zero counts.

Something like this:

```
    Gender    Class    EmployeeCount
    ---------------------------------
       M        1           0
       M        2           3
       M        3           1
       F        1           0
    ...
```

And so forth. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the way.  A `cross join` to generate the rows.  Then a `left join` to bring in the data and `group by` to aggregate:

```
select g.gender, c.class, count(l.gender) as cnt
from genders g cross join
     classes c left join
     list l
     on l.gender = g.gender and l.class = c.class
group by g.gender, c.class;
```

Comment: I'll give this a try ASAP. Was wondering about the count(l.gender). Is there a reason we are using gender as the count value, or does it not matter which one? Thanks!

Comment: @RobertGaum . . . Any column from `l` would do.  Normally, I would use the primary key but your question hasn't specified the layout of the table.